# count number of times and print line number of occurence of a string in a file by reading that file line by line

Tags: perl

when I am executing my code for first iteration it is working fine,but for other iteration it is not going into the for($row=0;$row=;$row++) loop.
so I am not getting the expected result .Please help.

```
@names =("error1","error2","error3");
my $filepath
="/home/acerun.log";
my $filepath1="/home/Perl/result6.log";
chomp($str);
open my $file,'<',$filepath or die "unable to open file :$!";
open my $file1,'>>',$filepath1 or die "unable to write to file :$!";
$count=0;
@line_num =();
@name=();
@number=();
foreach $str (@names){
  push(@name,$str);
  $i=0;
 for($row=0;$row=<$file>;$row++){
    chomp($row);
    if($row=~/$str/){
       push(@line_num,$.);     
       # print $file1 "$row \n";
       $i++;
       $count=1;
    }
    }
  push(@number,$i);
}

format Logfile = 
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<   @######               
 $Error_name                            $Number               
-----------------------------------------------------------
.

format Logfile_Top = 
-----------------------------------------------------------
Error_type                    number_of_times
----------------------------------------------------------- 
.
select($file1);
$~=Logfile;
$^=Logfile_Top;

$j=0;
foreach (@name){
    $Error_name = $_;
    $Number=$number[$j++];
    write;
}
```

expected result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Error_type                    number_of_times
-----------------------------------------------------------
error1                   36
-----------------------------------------------------------
error2                   35
-----------------------------------------------------------
error3                    17
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

actual result:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
Error_type                    number_of_times
-----------------------------------------------------------
error1                   36
-----------------------------------------------------------
error2                   0
-----------------------------------------------------------
error3                    0
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tip: I strongly recommend the Perl6::Form module (a module for Perl 5) over Perl 5's builtin forms.

Comment: Please show the input file `acerun.log` (or a part of it that reproduces the error)

Comment: @ikegami then what I can do to start reading again from first line.

Answer (score 2):

The inner loop is never entered for the names after the first one (`error2` and `error3`) because the file is already at EOF from looking for the first one (`error1`).

You could re-open the file for every name, but it's far simpler and faster to loop over the names for every line instead of reading the file for every name.

The following fixes this and other issues:

```
use strict;    # Always use this!!!
use warnings;  # Always use this!!!

my @names = qw( error1 error2 error3 );

my %counts = map { $_ => 0 } @names;
while (my $line = <>) {
   chomp($line);
   for my $name (@names) {
      ++$counts{$name} if $line =~ /\Q$name/;
   }
}

print(
   #12345678901234567890123456789 12345678901234567890123456789
   "-----------------------------------------------------------\n",
   "Error_type                    number_of_times\n",
   "-----------------------------------------------------------\n",
);

for my $name (@names) {
   printf("%-29s %29s\n", $name, $counts{$name});
}
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't get your logic.I have to read from one file and to write in another file in given format.you have not used any file handle to read and write .Can you post complete code according to my code.

Answer (score 0):

The C style `for` loop is wrong, you mix up $row with two different purposes, as both numeric [line number counter](http://p3rl.org/IO::Handle#input_line_number) and as a line read from the file handle. You need to separate the purposes. Use instead:

```
while (my $row = readline $file) {
    print $row;                         # line from file
    print $file->input_line_number;     # current line number of handle
}
```

Comment: Not the problem. I might be missing something, but I don't even know what you mean.

Comment: Recall what the three parts of C-style `for` do. Imagine $row contains "\n" after readline operation (empty line in file). At the end of the loop body, $row is numerically incremented. It would emit warning `Argument "\n" treated as 0 in increment (++) at …` Is the problem clear now?

Comment: I just noticed what you meant, but that code is purely useless. There's a lot of issues with the code, but that's one doesn't affect the outcome, and it's not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: Bro I have a file which contains around 2 millions of lines and I have to search some string's occurrence i.e. how many times it exists in that file.I want output in that format only as mentioned above in actual result.